# Stored procedure to create or update

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I am working on creating a Web API which will get account as the input parameter, which will have to create / update records in the table in SQL Server. So the web service will need to call the stored procedure which will accept the account. I created a sample table in the database with just two columns called `Account` and `CounterSeq`. I am trying to creating a stored procedure to create or update the records in the table.

[image]

Each account should have a `CounterSeq` associated with it. If the `Account` doesn't exists in the table, create `Account` name and associate `CounterSeq = 001` to it. If the `Account` name already exists, just update like `CounterSeq` to `CounterSeq + 1`

```
+---------+----------------+
| Account | CounterSeq     |
+---------+----------------+
| ABC     | 001            |          
| DEF     | 002            |     
+---------+----------------+
```

For this I create a TableType like this

```
USE [Demo]
GO

-- Create the data type
CREATE TYPE projectName_TT AS TABLE 
(
  Account      nvarchar(50),
  CounterSeq   int
)
GO
```

And the stored procedure as below but I am missing how to insert the new record like for a new `Account` how to set the `CounterSeq` to 001 ?

```
USE [Demo]
GO

 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInserorUpdateProjectName]
     @projectName_TT AS projectName_TT READONLY
 AS
 BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
 BEGIN TRANSACTION;
     UPDATE prj
     SET prj.Account = tt.Account,
         prj.CounterSeq = tt.CounterSeq + 1
     FROM dbo.[ProjectName] prj
     INNER JOIN @projectName_TT tt ON prj.Account = tt.Account

     INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProjectName](Account, CounterSeq)
         SELECT tt.Account, tt.CounterSeq
         FROM @projectName_TT tt 
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                           FROM [dbo].[ProjectName]
                           WHERE Account = tt.Account)

     COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe that the table you passed in should only have one field (based on your description **If the Account doesn't exists in the Database create Account name and associate CounterSeq 001 to it. If the Account name already exists just update like CounterSeq to CounterSeq+1**)

You can use this query (put it in your stored procedure between the `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT TRANSACTION`.

```
 MERGE dbo.[ProjectName] prj
 USING @projectName_TT tt
 ON prj.Account = tt.Account
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET prj.CounterSeq = prj.CounterSeq+1
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Account,CounterSeq)
 VALUES (tt.Account, 1);
```

Comment: I will need it to be 001 is that possible instead of just 1 ?

Comment: According to your description of the table (the picture), the data type is `int`. What you put in the database should have nothing to do with how it is displayed.

Comment: Just one last question is there anything wrong with having Seperate insert/update instead of merge.

Comment: No. It is just easier and shorter to use the `MERGE`.